# iterate each row in a spark dataframe and check if it each row contains a certain value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` that I would like to extract the values for each row in Spark-scala. In row one for example, it should extract `en` and `sv` which I would then put in a if condition.

```
+----------------+
|         Country|
+----------------+
|        [en, sv]| 
|            [sv]|
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object ArrayColumn extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("DataFrame-example")
  .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class C(country: Array[String])

  val df = Seq(
    C(Array("en", "sv")),
    C(Array("sv"))
  ).toDF()

  df.show(false)
  // +--------+
  // |country |
  // +--------+
  // |[en, sv]|
  // |[sv]    |
  // +--------+
  val uniqueDF = df.withColumn("uniqueID", monotonically_increasing_id)

  uniqueDF.show(false)
  // +--------+--------+
  // |country |uniqueID|
  // +--------+--------+
  // |[en, sv]|0       |
  // |[sv]    |1       |
  // +--------+--------+

  val resDF = uniqueDF.withColumn("countryOne", explode(col("country")))

  resDF.show(false)
  // +--------+--------+----------+                                                  
  // |country |uniqueID|countryOne|
  // +--------+--------+----------+
  // |[en, sv]|0       |en        |
  // |[en, sv]|0       |sv        |
  // |[sv]    |1       |sv        |
  // +--------+--------+----------+

  val resultDF = resDF.filter(col("countryOne").equalTo("en"))
  resultDF.show(false)
  // +--------+--------+----------+
  // |country |uniqueID|countryOne|
  // +--------+--------+----------+
  // |[en, sv]|0       |en        |
  // +--------+--------+----------+

}
```